# This is on the bottom of a bronze vase (Characters identified: 萬歷秊製)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Does anyone know what this means? Would love to know more about the period it was made. Is it an authentic piece or reproduction?[image]

Answer (score 2):

萬歷 = Wanli Era （1573—1620)

**Edit:**

萬曆 (Wanli) was a Ming Dynasty reign title (年號). As 水巷孑蠻 stated, 歷 is not the correct character, so it is most likely a fake

秊/nián/ Same as 年 = year

製 = made

萬歷秊製 = 萬曆年製 = Made during the Wanli Era (1573—1620)

Answer (score 2):

the correct term should be “萬曆”

## 曆 (u+66c6)

a real, authentic artefact made during the period ad 1573-1620, should not use the character “歷”; it’s very likely that it’s a fake product, pretending it’s made in 明 dynasty

[https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/万历](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E4%B8%87%E5%8E%86)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was 99% sure it was a reproduction. I don't have that kind of luck.